# Integral Inequality (Jensen's Inequality)

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to show that \begin{equation} \int_{\Omega}(|f(x)|^2+\delta|g(x)|^2)^{1/2} dx\ge \lbrace \|f\|_1^2+\delta\|g\|_1^2\rbrace^{1/2}.\end{equation} Here $\delta>0$. I understand that I have to use Jensen's inequality, but I am not able to get the proper form. Any help/hints?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you only need to prove that $\| f\|_1^2\leq \|f\|_2^2.$